# How do I add a pre-unit-test step to my top-level Makefile.am?

Tags: unit-testing, cross-platform, autotools, automake

What should I add to my top-level Makefile.am to cause `make check` to run a custom command before entering any subdirectory?

Here's some context:

When our `make check` process enters each subdirectory in our source code tree, it builds that subdirectory's unit test binary, copies the binary to a target hardware board using `scp`, and runs the binary remotely on the target using `ssh`.  We have more developers than we have boards, so we're sharing, and the target platform only has one user ID set up, so if two or more of us run `make check` at the same time, we clobber each other's unit test binaries on the target.

What I'd like is for `make check` to use a unique subdirectory on the target for each developer, probably in the home directory of the target's only user.  Before anything else is done during a `make check` run, I'll need to ensure that this subdirectory exists.

I'm hoping I can add a command along the lines of `ssh <board-ip> mkdir -p <unique-dirname-based-on-user>` to a variable or target in my top-level Makefile.am which will cause that command to be run at the start of a `make check` run, before any subdirectory is entered and any copying happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply make `check-recursive` depend on a target you want to execute.
e.g. add the following to your `Makefile.am`:

```
check-recursive: pre-check-recursive

.PHONY=pre-check-recursive
pre-check-recursive:
    @echo "called before running check recursively (YOUR CODE HERE)"
```